# How to increase the heigth of items using Jeremy Feinstein sliding menu?

Tags: android, slidingmenu, jfeinstein

I use Jeremy Feinsteins sliding menu and everything works well. But if I have a text for the item which is longer than two lines, then the text is not visible. 
Therefore I'm looking for a setting to change the height of an item. Is there a method to change the height of the item?

```
    Text //at the moment only this 
----------------
    Text // and this is possible
    Text
----------------
    Text //this is not possible
    Text
    Text
----------------
```